# Determine what program is used by gio open?

Tags: linux, terminal

By running `gio open --help` it can be seen that the command `gio open` will open files with the default application for that particular filetype.

How can I instead get an output of the application used to open that file in command-line form?

I am hoping for something like `gio open somefile.txt --print-application` which would for example output something like `gedit`.

Comment: Lookup `xdg-mime`, in particular the `query` subcommand

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `gio` for that, but you can use `xdg-mime` to query the file type of a file, and then use that to get the default application's description file:

```bash
# This prints the mime type of somefile.txt
xdg-mime query filetype somefile.txt
# Output, for example: text/plain

# This queries the default application that opens a mime type
xdg-mime query default text/plain
# Output, for example: gedit.desktop
```

You can combine these two things through process substitution; or put them in a shell function:

```bash
# do a substitution to do this on one line
xdg-mime query default $(xdg-mime query filetype somefile.txt)

# Or make a small function that solves the whole thing:
function get_handler_application() {
  filetype="$(xdg-mime query filetype "$1")"
  xdg-mime query default "${filetype}"
}
# call like:
# get_handler_application somefile.txt
```

But the truth is that you'll find the result you get is *not* an executable, but a .desktop file – which is an important feature, because desktop files contain all the options that your programs want to be called with.

You can find these desktop files in the directories called "applications" underneath each `:`-separated path in the environment variable `$XDG_DATA_DIRS`.

If your shell is `zsh`, handling that can be quite graceful:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/zsh
# Copyright 2023 Marcus Müller
# SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-or-later

# We can get the name of the file handler this way,
# for example:
#   get_handler_application aaargh.txt
# outputs:
# text/plain
function get_handler_application() {
  filetype="$(xdg-mime query filetype "$1")"
  xdg-mime query default "${filetype}"
}

# Get the full path to the specific file that opens this file
# There's multiple paths, and user-defined ones take priority
# over system-defined ones. For example:
#   get_handler_desktop_file aaargh.txt
# outputs:
# pluma.desktop
function get_handler_desktop_file(){
  desktop_fname="$(get_handler_application "$1")"
  for candidate in ${(ps.:.)XDG_DATA_DIRS}; do
    fullpath="${candidate}/applications/${desktop_fname}"
    [[ -r "${fullpath}" ]] && printf '%s' ${fullpath} && break
  done
}

# Get all the commands that are specified in the desktop file.
# There can be multiple, because some file handlers have extended 
# options for opening things, like "open in new window" or "make
# new document from this template.
# For example:
#   get_handler_command_lines holygrail.html
# outputs:
# firefox %u
# firefox --new-window %u
# firefox --private-window %u
# firefox --ProfileManager
function get_handler_command_lines() {
  sed -n 's/^Exec=\(.*\)*/\1/p' "$(get_handler_desktop_file "$1")"
}
```

Comment: honestly, if someone with a command line background has a zsh/bash portable way of doing "for each element in this `:`-separated list of directories, try whether a file below exists and return the first hit", I'd be interested.

Comment: Your answer seems convincing. But, it seems to point to `libreoffice --writer` as the executable used to open a simple `README.txt` file, whereas the command `gio open` uses `gedit`.

Comment: hm, in that case glib deviates from freedesktop? That is surprising!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `gio` only, in two steps:
Get the content-type (that is, the mime type) via `gio info`:

```
gio info -a standard::content-type clip.mp4
```

which prints something like:

```
uri: file:///home/tmp/clip.mp4
attributes:
    standard::content-type: video/mp4
```

Now that you know the mime type you can run

```
gio mime video/mp4
```

which prints all the registered handlers for that mime type. The default one is listed first:

```
Default application for 'video/mp4': mpv.desktop
Registered applications:
        mpv.desktop
        smplayer.desktop
Recommended applications:
        mpv.desktop
        smplayer.desktop
```

So, in this case, `gio` will use `mpv` to `open` the file `clip.mp4`

Comment: Attributes section is empty when I run the command for some reason.

Comment: @Fahrradkette -  works fine here with `gio 2.76.4` . If you run just `gio info filename` do you get a long list of attributes and is _content-type_ (or _fast-content-type_ ) among them?